# "Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46"

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

this is my code

```
$URL='';(url of third party api)        
$simple  = simplexml_load_file($URL);

 foreach($simple->FEEDBACK as $result){

  $service_score=$result->SERVICESTARRATING;
  $service_feedback=$result->CUSTOMERCOMMENT;
  $vendor_reply=$result->VENDORCOMMENT;

  $orderId =Mage::getModel('sales/order')->
           loadByIncrementId($order_ref)->getEntityId(); 

  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

 $order->setData('score',$service_score);
 $order->setData('service_feedback',$service_feedback);
 $order->setData('response',$vendor_reply);
```

upto this code is working properly,when i try to use..

```
$order->save();
```

its give error as written in title,please help..

Answer (score 0):

First: 
you don't have to load Order again after you loaded with increment_id. You can load `$order`:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_ref);
$order->setData('score',$service_score);
$order->setData('service_feedback',$service_feedback);
$order->setData('response',$vendor_reply);
```

Check if fields `score`, `service_feedback` and `response` exists in database table: `sales_flat_order`. I think these fields do not exists in table or the data you assign different than expected so you cannot save the order.